# Windows XP, identify USB from Device Manager

Tags: windows-xp, usb

In Windows' [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager), how do I identify which USB device is which port (from 3-4 physical ports) on a desktop/laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to identify devices which are currently connected to your USB ports, if that's what you mean. If not, and you wish to identify which device is in what physical port - then no. USB ports are the same.

(technically, they're something of a serial port variety, but you still have to means of differentiating between them - unlike old COMs)

Comment: thanks for the USBDeview, this pretty much made it, the neat thing is that it keeps tracks of "Last Pluged/Unplug Data" so you can identify the device (physical to logical) easily, so I could solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The different physical connections in a USB hub are not in any way electrically distinct.  It's a "bus" architecture (hence 'USB'), so, no there's not really any way to do what you're asking.